# Javascript:: Trigger firstChild element by class

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid, classname

This code would speak for it self and explain what I'm trying to achieve...

```
<style>
.red{background:red}
.blue{background:blue}
</style>

<div id=test>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
</div>

<script>
var firstBtn=document.getElementById("test").firstChild.className;

(firstBtn!="red")?firstBtn="red":firstBtn="blue";
</script>
```

Here is the jsFiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/hnfeje2q/

Very simple but since I'm new to JavaScript...

Thanks!

Comment: `firstElementChild` is a more reliable and useful version of `firstChild`. It will ignore any text node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get the div wrapper with id=test and then load the first child element inside that wrapper with the code below and then you can add the class 'red' to that element/button.

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("test");
var firstButton = wrapper.childNodes[1];

// if the button doesn't have a red class, set it
if(firstButton.className.indexOf('red') == -1) {
    firstButton.className = firstButton.className + ' red';
}
```

or go with the query selector

```
var firstButton = document.querySelector('#test button:first-child');
if(firstButton && firstButton.className.indexOf('red') == -1) {
    firstButton.className = firstButton.className + ' red';
}
```

Comment: .childNodes[1] is the second child element, not the first one

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan .childNodes[1] is the same as .children[0], element node, but .childNodes[0] is a text node and not element node. You can find out more about node types [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp).

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById("test").firstChild` is not a reference to the first `button` as you might expect, but to a text node (that is the space between the open `<div id="test">` tag and the first `button` element.

use instead `document.querySelector('#test button:first-child')` to get a reference to the first `button` element

```
var firstBtn = document.querySelector('#test button:first-child');
firstBtn.className = (firstBtn.className !== "red")? "red" : "blue";
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnfeje2q/3/)

```
var firstBtn = document.querySelector('#test button:first-child');

if (firstBtn !== "red") {
    firstBtn.className = "red";
} else {
    firstBtn.className = "blue";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using firstChild, use childNodes.  Also, firstBtn is simply going to be a string with the name of the class.  To change it, you actually need to set the className on the button using a similar syntax.

```
var firstBtn=document.getElementById("test").childNodes[1].className;
(firstBtn!="red")?document.getElementById("test").childNodes[1].className="red":document.getElementById("test").childNodes[1].className="blue";
```